# Can I implement Factory-pattern construction without using new()?

Tags: c++, initialization, factory-pattern

At the moment I'm dealing with a delightful legacy code class implementing polymorphism by switch-case:

```cpp
class LegacyClass {
 public:
    enum InitType {TYPE_A, TYPE_B};
    void init(InitType type) {m_type=type;}

    int foo() {
        if (m_type==TYPE_A) 
        { 
            /* ...A-specific work... */
            return 1;
        }
        // else, TYPE_B:
        /* ...B-specific work... */
        return 2;
    }

    /** Lots more functions like this **/

  private:
    InitType m_type;
 };
```

I'd like to refactor this to proper polymorphism, e.g.:

```cpp
class RefactoredClass {
 public:
    virtual ~RefactoredClass(){}
    virtual int foo()=0;
 };

 class Class_ImplA : public RefactoredClass {
 public:
    virtual ~Class_ImplA(){}
    int foo() {
        /* ...A-specific work... */
        return 1;
    }
 };

class Class_ImplB : public RefactoredClass {
 public:
    virtual ~Class_ImplB(){}
    int foo() {
        /* ...B-specific work... */
        return 2;
    }
 };
```

Unfortunately, I have one crucial problem: due to optimization and architectural considerations, within a primary use of `LegacyClass`, I cannot use dynamic allocation; the instance is a member of a different class by composition:

```cpp
 class BigImportantClass{
    /* ... */
  private:
    LegacyClass m_legacy;
 }
```

(In this example, `BigImportantClass` may be dynamically allocated, but the allocation needs to be in one continuous virtual segment, and a single `new()` call; I can't make further calls to `new()` in the `BigImportantClass` ctor or in subsequent initialization methods.)

**Is there a good way to initialize a concrete implementation, polymorphically, without using `new()`?**

---

My own progress so far: What I *can* do is provide a `char[]` buffer as a member of `BigImportantClass`, and somehow initialize a concrete member of `RefactoredClass` in that memory. The buffer would be large enough to accommodate all implementations of `RefactoredClass`. However, I do not know how to do this safely. I know the placement-new syntax, but I'm new to dealing with alignment (hence, warned off by [the C++-FAQ...](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/placement-new.html)), and aligning generically for all concrete implementations of the `RefactoredClass` interface sounds daunting. Is this the way to go? Or do I have any other options?

Comment: You could keep the polymorphic hierarchy private to some ambient class and only use dynamic allocation internally.

Comment: If you know which implementation you need before the `BigImportantClass` constructor, you might be able to use a template.

Comment: @Wimmel : I'm considering a template - that'd be quick! - but that means dragging the implementation choice up to a much more visible level (`BigImportantClass` becomes `BigImportantClass<TYPE_A>`). It's definitely an option, though.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I don't understand quite what you mean by that. I hope my explanation was clear, but I don't want, say, `Class_ImplA` to be dynamically allocated on its own, in a seperate `new()`. It should be instantiated along with `BigImportantClass`, as a member by composition.

Comment: @Ziv You can hide the implementation choice in a factory function, like `CreateBigImportantClass()`, which can even be a static member.

Comment: @Jefffrey: I'm simplifying somewhat here, but I can simplify even further: My architect told me to. :P

Comment: @Ziv: Like `class RefactorClass { class ImplBase { /* ... */ }; ImplBase * impl; /* ... */ }` etc. Keep the actual implementation classes as private member classes of `RefactorClass`.

Comment: You can initialize a concrete member of RefactoredClass in that char buffer memory using placement new.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN : That's my leading option at the moment. My concern there is alignment issues, which I know zilch about, and haven't learned enough about yet (see the last paragraph in my post). If you're able to explain how to handle alignment safely and reliably for this case of placement-new, that'd be marvelous.

Comment: I don't understand how `BigImportantClass` and the `RefactoredClass` hierarchy are related.

Comment: You do realise this any virtual dispatch to small functions likely be significantly slower than the Legacy switch?  Anyway, don't put a `char[]` in `BigImportantClass`, replace `LegacyClass` with a class than embeds an aligned buffer.  You can probably get away using a union of a `double` and `char[]` - hardly anything needs more alignment than `double`.  The Replacement class should have a function to get a reference or pointer to the placement-`new`ed object.

Comment: @TonyD: Ooooh, that sounds promising. You're also right that the performance hit might be a problem (although I'm interested in this question regardless).

Comment: Well, you can work with Kerrek's suggestion above about `class RefactorClass` containing the types and the buffer, keeping everything encapsulated.  Not good to have a `ImplBase*` member though... you know it'll be at the start of the buffer so just need a function to return that on demand.

Comment: You could write a custom allocator which takes memory from a custom aligned contiguous chunk of memory

Comment: If you really need one big block of memory containing various subclasses of BigImportantClass then you can use union or as you already said submit your own memory address in new(mymemory) MyClass(...). Both paths have pros and cons. Calculating the alignments is not complicated, a lot of sizeof. If you can't execute the various ctors in the same function then for each subclass create a static function that extract the correct memory address from BigImportantClass.

Comment: "My concern there is alignment issues" - instead of char[] buffer (alignment 1), you can achieve uint32_t alignment (4) by using a uint32_t[] buffer  (or alignment (8) using uint64_t, etc.) into which you can placement new.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN: Thank you. I'm trying to understand what the precise alignment restriction is - I need alignment to be (a multiple of) the largest POD type that's contained (by composition) in the allocated class, right? But if I don't know what subclasses might be used, or their composition, I'm basically guessing (or making some kind of worst-case assumption?), is that correct?

Comment: The only alignment you can control is the 1st byte of the data attributes of a class or struct ... because neither C nor C++ have memory layout semantics.  i.e. If the biggest POD (plain-old-data) is 8 bytes long, IMHO you can not do wrong using alignment 8, i.e. 8 will always be enough regardless of the derived class data attributes (so, use array of uint64_t). In other words, alignment 2 or 1 will be handled correctly by alignment 8. (Perhaps my understanding of alignment is different than yours?)

Comment: making some kind of worst-case assumption?), is that correct?  -- yes, and in some cases, you might waste up to 7 of the 8 bytes (using uint64_t)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some code... just doing the obvious things.  I don't use [C++11's new `union` features](https://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=556), which might actually be a more structured way to ensure appropriate alignment and size and clean up the code.

```
#include <iostream>

template <size_t A, size_t B>
struct max
{
    static const size_t value = A > B ? A : B;
};

class X
{
  public:
    X(char x) { construct(x); }

    X(const X& rhs)
        { rhs.interface().copy_construct_at_address(this); }

    ~X() { interface().~Interface(); }

    X& operator=(const X& rhs)
    {
        // warning - not exception safe
        interface().~Interface();
        rhs.interface().copy_construct_at_address(this);
        return *this;
    }

    struct Interface
    {
        virtual ~Interface() { }
        virtual void f(int) = 0;
        virtual void copy_construct_at_address(void*) const = 0;
    };

    Interface& interface()
        { return reinterpret_cast<Interface&>(data_); }

    const Interface& interface() const
        { return reinterpret_cast<const Interface&>(data_); }

    // for convenience use of virtual members...
    void f(int x) { interface().f(x); }

  private:
    void construct(char x)
    {
             if (x == 'A') new (data_) Impl_A();
        else if (x == 'B') new (data_) Impl_B();
    }

    struct Impl_A : Interface
    {
        Impl_A() : n_(10) { std::cout << "Impl_A(this " << this << ")\n"; }
        ~Impl_A() { std::cout << "~Impl_A(this " << this << ")\n"; }
        void f(int x)
            { std::cout << "Impl_A::f(x " << x << ") n_ " << n_;
              n_ += x / 3;
              std::cout << " -> " << n_ << '\n'; }
        void copy_construct_at_address(void* p) const { new (p) Impl_A(*this); }
        int n_;
    };

    struct Impl_B : Interface
    {
        Impl_B() : n_(20) { std::cout << "Impl_B(this " << this << ")\n"; }
        ~Impl_B() { std::cout << "~Impl_B(this " << this << ")\n"; }
        void f(int x)
            { std::cout << "Impl_B::f(x " << x << ") n_ " << n_;
              n_ += x / 3.0;
              std::cout << " -> " << n_ << '\n'; }
        void copy_construct_at_address(void* p) const { new (p) Impl_B(*this); }
        double n_;
    };

    union
    {
        double align_;
        char data_[max<sizeof Impl_A, sizeof Impl_B>::value];
    };
};

int main()
{
    {
        X a('A');
        a.f(5);

        X b('B');
        b.f(5);
        X x2(b);
        x2.f(6);
        x2 = a;
        x2.f(7);
    }
}
```

Output (with my comments):

```
Impl_A(this 0018FF24)
Impl_A::f(x 5) n_ 10 -> 11
Impl_B(this 0018FF04)
Impl_B::f(x 5) n_ 20 -> 21.6667
Impl_B::f(x 6) n_ 21.6667 -> 23.6667
~Impl_B(this 0018FF14)           // x2 = a morphs type
Impl_A::f(x 7) n_ 11 -> 13       // x2 value 11 copied per a's above
~Impl_A(this 0018FF14)
~Impl_B(this 0018FF04)
~Impl_A(this 0018FF24)
```

Answer (score 2):

I implemented this using C++11 unions.  This code seems to work under g++ 4.8.2, but it requires the -std=gnu++11 or -std=c++11 flags.

```
#include <iostream>

class RefactoredClass {
  public:
  virtual ~RefactoredClass() { }; // Linking error if this is pure.  Why?
  virtual int foo() = 0;
};

class RefactorA : RefactoredClass {
  double data1, data2, data3, data4;

  public:
  int foo() { return 1; }
  ~RefactorA() { std::cout << "Destroying RefactorA" << std::endl; }
};

class RefactorB : RefactoredClass {
  int data;

  public:
  int foo () { return 2; }
  ~RefactorB() { std::cout << "Destroying RefactorB" << std::endl; }
};

// You may need to manually create copy, move, &ct operators for this.
// Requires C++11
union LegacyClass {
  RefactorA refA;
  RefactorB refB;

  LegacyClass(char type) { 
    switch (type) {
      case 'A':
        new(this) RefactorA;
        break;
      case 'B':
        new(this) RefactorB;
        break;
      default:
        // Rut-row
        break;
    }
  }

  RefactoredClass * AsRefactoredClass() { return (RefactoredClass *)this; }

  int foo() { return AsRefactoredClass()->foo(); }

  ~LegacyClass() { AsRefactoredClass()->~RefactoredClass(); }

};

int main (void) {
  LegacyClass A('A');
  LegacyClass B('B');

  std::cout << A.foo() << std::endl;
  std::cout << B.foo() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 - not bad ;-).  "Linking error if this is pure.  Why?" - as objects are destroyed, the destructors run from most-derived back to base... destroying any data members, setting the pointer to the virtual dispatch table back too so overrides from already destroyed levels of derived class aren't used....

Answer (score 0):

Somebody should have made an answer by now...so here's mine.

I'd recommend using a union of char array and one of the biggest integer types:

```
union {
    char refactored_class_buffer[ sizeof RefactoredClass ];
    long long refactored_class_buffer_aligner;
};
```

I also strongly recommend putting an assert or even an if(check) throw; into your factory so that you never, ever, exceed the size of your buffer.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is the same for each case, and you're only changing behaviuor, you don't need to allocate in your core - this is basically a strategy pattern using singleton strategies. You end up using polymorphism in your logic, but not in your data.

```
class FooStrategy() {
virtual int foo(RefactoredClass& v)=0;
}

class RefactoredClass {
   int foo() {
     return this.fooStrategy(*this);
   }
   FooStrategy * fooStrategy;
};

class FooStrategyA : public FooStrategy {

   //Use whichever singleton pattern you're happy with.
   static FooStrategyA* instance() {
      static FooStrategyA fooStrategy;
      return &fooStrategy;
   }

   int foo(RefactoredClass& v) {
      //Do something with v's data
   }
}

//Same for FooStrategyB
```

Then when you create a `RefactoredClass` you set its `fooStrategy` to `FooStrategyA::instance()`.